# Highlighting nav without jquery

Tags: javascript, nav, highlighting

I have a web page with anchor links and I wish for them to stay highlighted when they are clicked AND when the user manually scrolls down. I have seen some jquery code here codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/mhCyx that does what I wish to do, however I wish to achieve this effect using raw javascript and I can't see it posted anywhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: youmightnotneedjquery.com has a list of some conversions you can try.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for animated scrolling and scrollspy functionality? Shameless plug for two native JS (non-jQuery) scripts I wrote that are designed to work together:

- Smooth Scroll: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll
- Gumshoe for scrollspy: https://github.com/cferdinandi/gumshoe

Comment: Thanks, will give those a try!